# Existence of a function satisfying zero boundary conditions for fractional Laplacian (1d)

Tags: real-analysis, boundary-value-problem, fractional-calculus, unbounded-operators

Does there exists a non-zero function $$f\in C_0([0,1]):=\{f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R:\ f\text{ is continuous and } f(0)=f(1)=0\},$$ such that $(-\Delta)^{\frac\alpha 2}f\in C_0([0,1]) $, where $(-\Delta)^{\frac\alpha 2}$ is the Dirichlet fractional Laplacian defined by
$$
(-\Delta)^{\frac\alpha 2}f(x):=\int_0^1(f(x)-f(y))\frac{dy}{|x-y|^{1+\alpha}}+f(x)\int_{\mathbb R\backslash (0,1)}\frac{dy}{|x-y|^{1+\alpha}},\ \ x\in(0,1),
$$
and $(-\Delta)^{\frac\alpha 2}f(0):=\lim_{x\to 0^+}(-\Delta)^{\frac\alpha 2}f(x)$, $(-\Delta)^{\frac\alpha 2}f(1):=\lim_{x\to 1^-}(-\Delta)^{\frac\alpha 2}f(x)$, where $\alpha \in(0,2)$ (principal value definition of the first integral).

My question is motivated by the last part of [Theorem 2.7](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.06421.pdf), as the existence of the function I am looking for would allow me to apply that theorem.

Note that the above definition of $(-\Delta)^{\frac \alpha 2}$  agrees with the definition of  the restricted fractional Laplacian in [formula (3.1) here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.07871.pdf), which differs from definition of the spectral fractional Laplacian in [formula (3.4) here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.07871.pdf).

[Mathoverflow crosspost](https://mathoverflow.net/q/294462/120741)

Comment: Are you asking whether there is *just one* function with the requested properties, or whether *all* functions with the properties you mention are continuous? Because in the first case you need only taking a $C^\infty$ function satisfying the given boundary conditions. Use the Fourier characterization of the fractional Laplacian, it is much easier.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: I ask for just one function with the requested properties. It is not obvious to me how  to find a function in $C_0([0,1])$ such that  the (Dirichlet) fractional Laplacian defined above preserves the boundary condition, i.e. $(-\Delta)^{\frac\alpha 2}f(0)=(-\Delta)^{\frac\alpha 2}f(1)=0$.

Comment: It is a good idea to add a link to the Mathoverflow cross-posting

Answer (score 1):

**CLAIM**. If $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ and supported in $[a, b]\subset (0, 1)$ then $(-\Delta)^{\frac a2}f\in C^\infty(0,1)$ and it satisfies the Dirichlet boundary conditions on $[0, 1]$.

*Proof*. (Sketchy) Let $(\phi_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be a sequence of orthonormal Dirichlet eigenfunctions. We decompose 
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \hat{f}(n)\phi_n(x).$$ 
By the smoothness assumption, the sequence $\hat{f}(n)$ decays faster than any polynomial, and so 
$$
(-\Delta)^{\frac a 2} f = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^a\hat{f}(n)\phi_n(x)$$ 
is an absolutely convergent series.

*Remark*. In this post, the Dirichlet fractional Laplacian is defined by the formula 
$$(-\Delta)^{\frac{a}{2}}f(x) : = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^a \hat f(n) \phi_n(x).$$

Comment: I don't get it sorry. I do not see how you can prove that $(-\Delta)^{\frac\alpha 2}f$ will be zero at the boundary. For instance  $(-\Delta)^{\frac\alpha 2}f(0)\neq 0$ for the every function positive on a subset of $(0,1)$ and zero elsewhere.

Comment: Right, that's a mistake. I need to redo this directly with the Dirichlet Laplacian. Give me a couple minutes

Comment: Done. Don't hesitate to ask if you find it too sketchy.

Comment: I believe your proof is correct, but then your Dirichlet fractional Laplacian does not agree with the one I defined (at least as one 
 approachs the boundary), right?

Comment: Frankly, I don't know. However, it should be that "your" Laplacian and "my" Laplacian are the same, perhaps with a non-trivial proof. One should find the result in the literature but I don't know where to start. I vaguely recall a paper of Caffarelli and Silvestre on these things...

Comment: 'Your' operator is exponentiating the eigenvalues of the $\phi_n$'s, as in the definition  of the spectral fractional Laplacian (3.4) in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.07871.pdf. 'My' definition is instead a version of the restricted fractional Laplacian (3.1) in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.07871.pdf, and they do not agree in general. Also my question is motivated by the last part of Theorem 2.7 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.06421.pdf, as the existence of the function I am looking for would allow me to apply that theorem.

Comment: Dang. Maybe you should add these links to the main post. I don't think that the difference between the various fractional Laplacians is widely known.